# Generated tags in xslt are not being closed correctly

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xhtml, w3c

I'm trying to get the `meta` and `img` tags to close in the output from an xslt.

I've looked into it, and it seems I need to select an "xml" method rather than "html", but this still doesn't seem to work.

I've currently got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl">

    <xsl:output method="xml"
                omit-xml-declaration="yes"
                indent="yes"
                encoding="iso-8859-1"
                doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"
                doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" />

    <!-- ... -->

    <meta name="keywords" content="{meta/data/here/text()}" />

    <!-- ... -->
```

Am I doing anything that is obviously wrong?

Comment: What output do you currently get for your meta tag?

Comment: Also, what xslt processor are you using?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to generate xhtml, so the meta tag closes such as <meta ... /> instead of <meta ... > ? We need more information

Answer (score 1):

I can replicate the non-terminating meta tag with msxsl. This can be fixed by setting the xmlns to the XHTML standard (xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml") on the xsl:stylesheet element. I've found in the past that msxsl has a number of problems with XSLT processing. Besides which, it's pretty much deprecated.

Comment: Which version of msxml? msxml 6.0 is not deprecated as far as I know. What makes you think so?

Comment: The XSLT processor I used was msxsl.exe, not msxml. msxsl.exe uses msxml version 4. msxml is not deprecated.